# Change ShortCut Icon programmatically

Tags: delphi, winapi, shortcut

I create a shortcut with following codes.

```
  var MyObject  : IUnknown;
  var MySLink   : IShellLink;
  var MyPFile   : IPersistFile;

  MyObject := CreateComObject(CLSID_ShellLink);
  MySLink  := MyObject as IShellLink;
  MyPFile  := MyObject as IPersistFile;
  with MySLink do
  begin
    SetPath(PChar(sExePath + sExeName));
    SetArguments(PChar (sParams));
    SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(sExePath));
  end;
  MyPFile.Save(PWChar(WideString(GetDesktopFolder + '\MyApp.lnk')), False);
```

But I want to change the shortcut icon.

For example, I make a shortcut for NOTEPAD.EXE on my DESKTOP. so How can I change its ICON.
When you RIGHT click on the shortcut, choose properties, then you can see a button named **"CHANGE ICON"**, that's it what I want.

How can I do that with code ?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw-seticonlocation

Comment: Thank you so much.
I looked that, but I missed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks @Jonahatan

Links
[IShellLinkW::SetIconLocation method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishelllinkw-seticonlocation)

Code Sample

```
  with MySLink do
  begin
    SetPath(PChar(sExePath + sExeName));
    SetArguments(PChar (sParams));
    SetWorkingDirectory(PChar(sExePath));
    SetIconLocation(PWideChar(sNewIconFileName),0);
  end;
```